# python pyside6 qtextedit synchronize error

Tags: python, synchronization, pyside

I have a pyside6 app which has 2 TextEdit widgets and I want the 2 TextEdits to scroll in sync.
The following code is used for this function:

```
    self.scrollconnect1 = self.TextEdit_1.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
        self.TextEdit_2.verticalScrollBar().setValue)
    self.scrollconnect2 = self.TextEdit_2.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
        self.TextEdit_1.verticalScrollBar().setValue)
```

It works fine when there are few lines in TextEdit, but if there are too many lines (about 50,000 lines) in both TextEdit, it will not precisely synchronize in the same line. (Especially when I scroll the widget by both mouse wheel and scroll bar).
How to keep them synchronized precisely?

Following code is for test:

```
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ScrollBar(QtWidgets.QScrollBar):
    valueUpdated = QtCore.Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setTracking(True)
        self.actionTriggered.connect(self.handleAction)

    def handleAction(self, action):
        action = QtWidgets.QAbstractSlider.SliderAction(action)
        print(self.objectName(), action, (self.value(), self.sliderPosition()))
        if self.value() != self.sliderPosition():
            self.valueUpdated.emit(self.sliderPosition())


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.editTop = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.editBtm = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.editTop.setVerticalScrollBar(
            ScrollBar(self, objectName='EDIT-TOP'))
        self.editBtm.setVerticalScrollBar(
            ScrollBar(self, objectName='EDIT-BTM'))
        self.editTop.verticalScrollBar().actionTriggered.connect(
            lambda a: self.editBtm.verticalScrollBar().triggerAction(
                QtWidgets.QAbstractSlider.SliderAction(a)))
        self.editTop.verticalScrollBar().valueUpdated.connect(
            self.editBtm.verticalScrollBar().setValue)
        self.editBtm.verticalScrollBar().valueUpdated.connect(
            self.editTop.verticalScrollBar().setValue)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.editTop)
        layout.addWidget(self.editBtm)
        line = ' text' * 40
        # for index in range(50000):
        for index in range(500):
            self.editTop.insertPlainText("\n"+str(index) + line)
            self.editBtm.insertPlainText("\n"+str(index) + line)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(800, 100, 600, 400)
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: The code in your question is not valid. Please provide a proper [mre] so that others can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, the codes I provided is wrong. Now the code is correct. Just need to create two TextEdit widget named TextEdit_1 and TextEdit_2 to test them.

Comment: No, you're the one asking, so it's *your* responsibility to create a proper test-case and add it to the question.

Comment: I add them to my topic now, sorry.

Comment: They do scroll in sync as long as both text editors have the same number of lines.

Comment: Not actually, both text editors have the same 50,000 lines, and after scrolling up and down for a while, it gets out of sync.

Comment: [QTBUG-25365](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-25365) documents some closely related issues with `valueChanged` signals that are specific to QPlainTextEdit. This bug seems to mostly apply to keyboard actions, but it could plausibly affect some mouse actions as well. I cannot reproduce the behaviour described in the question, but I can confirm that keyboard actions never emit `valueChanged` in a QPlainTextEdit, whereas they always do in a QTextEdit (which is unaffected by this bug). So the question is: can you reproduce the behaviour you describe using QTextEdit?

Comment: (Sorry I accidentally pressed send button.)
1. Paste the same string to both QTextEdits (anything, I pasted 50,000 lines of text and they are the same content.)
2. Drag the scroll bar to move up and down (for example, move to the bottom)
3. Use the mouse wheel to move the content up and down.
4. You will see that the QTextEdit is out of sync.

Comment: I cannot reproduce any of that - it all works perfectly fine for me on Linux using both Qt-6.4.0 and Qt-5.15.6. What platform are you on and what *specific* version of Qt are you using? Can you try testing with a different mouse?

Comment: I used pyside6 version 6.4.0 on windows 11 and found it only happened after drag the scrollbar (especially drag it to the bottom) then use mouse wheel to scroll the content. Just dragging the scroll bar or just using the mouse wheel to move content does not cause this problem.
I tried another mouse, and still happens.

Comment: Does the issue occur *after* the text has fully loaded in *both* editors? Also - does appending 50k lines programmatically using a for-loop make any difference?

Comment: Maybe the question is about word wrapping.
also, the maximum of the scrollbar are changed after drag the scrollbar.
I've tested appending 50,000 lines through a for loop and the problem occurs if those lines have word wrapping.
Move to the bottom and scroll up by mouse wheel can observed this situation more clearly.
But it doesn't happen when there is no word wrap.
I'll post the test code to my topic.

Comment: It's still totally unclear what the problem is. It would help if you numbered the lines so it's clear which line should be at the top/bottom of the view - so do `.appendPlainText(f"{i} for test ...")` in the loop instead. For me, this displays line 49999 at the bottom of both views on load, and a single wheel-scroll notch brings 49998 into view and so forth. Dragging the scroll-bar always keeps both views in sync. Try to find the *smallest* change that will reproduce the issue (if you still can).

Comment: Okay, but I have no other ideas. Still thank you.

Comment: Just for the record: can you spell out what you see compared to what I outlined above? What exactly happens when you scroll the mouse-wheel by a single notch? Presumably there's some kind of visible offset - but how much is it? Is the offset consistent? (This all assumes you have a mouse with a notchy wheel, rather than smooth-scrolling).

Comment: I've updated a video to show this situation.
https://youtu.be/1vH3xHXov-E

Comment: It's hard to tell from that video what's happening because you're making lots of random actions very quickly, and you only operate on the top editor. To debug this, you need to make small, precise adjustments to pinpoint which specifc action causes the problem. It would help a lot if you also used QTextEdits, because that would allow you to make adjustments using only the keyboard. If you ***can't*** reproduce the problem using the keyboard, that could be quite significant. Narrowing the problem down to a more specific cause might mean it's possible to find a work-around.

Comment: Using the keyboard will directly cause the two TextEdit to be out of sync.

Comment: That srongly suggests internal calls to `setValue()` just don't emit `valueChanged`, so the other slider won't move. You could try connecting to the `sliderMoved` signal instead. If that doesn't work, it will narrow things a down as little more. What happens when you switch scrolling between the two editors? Do they eventually come back into sync? (PS: if you're not interested in pursuing this any further, please say so).

Comment: https://youtu.be/d2I7P909d0c
Changed the signal to sliderMoved.
I'm still trying to figure out why.
Or is there another way (not by connecting to scrollbars) to connect two TextEdits?

Comment: Well, the point of all this is to try to find another way. I have added a test script as a community wiki below. Can you please try it? If the problem is still there, what output do you see? On my system, when I scroll the **TOP** editor, I always see pairs of `EDIT-TOP`/`EDIT-BTM` in the output. Try it with both 500 and 50000 lines, to see if there's any difference.

Comment: In the test script, it worked when I just use scrollbar to move it, if use text cursor to move it, it will out of sync.
https://youtu.be/qOXLQmst4ys
Test video, `EDIT-TOP` and `EDIT-BTM` will not show in pair.
If I change the `TextEdit` to `PlainTextEdit`, it will show the behavior like my another video:
https://youtu.be/TGUlJY5JFWg and the test code I will post to my main topic (changed `TextEdit` to `PlainTextEdit` and the way `.appendPlainText` to append text).

Comment: Also, 500 lines results are similar to 50,000 lines.

Comment: I have added a new script. Please test it by dragging the scroll-bar, scrolling with wheel, page-up/page-down keys, and arrow keys. Do they **all** work with both 500 and 50000 lines?

Comment: When there are no word wrapping, new script works well with both 500 and 50000 lines.
But if there have word wrapping, it happens again.
video: https://youtube.com/shorts/OusbneSjXvs

Comment: I have now found I can reproduce the problem in QPLainTextEdit (but not QTextEdit) if I drag the slider **very** quickly. It seems that with word-wrapping, the scroll-bar adjustments may happen too slowly, so some changes are missed. I think your mouse hardware is quicker than mine, so you see the problem more often. This is a Qt limitation that probably cannot be avoided. The only work-around may be to disable word-wrapping.

Comment: OK, I got it. Thank you very much for your help these days, disable word-wrapping might be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test Script:

```
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class ScrollBar(QtWidgets.QScrollBar):
    valueUpdated = QtCore.Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setTracking(True)
        self.actionTriggered.connect(self.handleAction)

    def handleAction(self, action):
        action = QtWidgets.QAbstractSlider.SliderAction(action)
        print(self.objectName(), action, (self.value(), self.sliderPosition()))
        if self.value() != self.sliderPosition():
            self.valueUpdated.emit(self.sliderPosition())

    def sliderChange(self, change):
        change = QtWidgets.QAbstractSlider.SliderChange(change)
        if (change == QtWidgets.QAbstractSlider.SliderValueChange and
            self.signalsBlocked()):
            self.blockSignals(False)
            print(self.objectName(), change, self.value())
            self.valueUpdated.emit(self.value())
        super().sliderChange(change)

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#         self.editTop = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
#         self.editBtm = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.editTop = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.editBtm = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.editTop.setVerticalScrollBar(
            ScrollBar(self, objectName='EDIT-TOP'))
        self.editBtm.setVerticalScrollBar(
            ScrollBar(self, objectName='EDIT-BTM'))
        self.editTop.verticalScrollBar().valueUpdated.connect(
            self.editBtm.verticalScrollBar().setValue)
        self.editBtm.verticalScrollBar().valueUpdated.connect(
            self.editTop.verticalScrollBar().setValue)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.editTop)
        layout.addWidget(self.editBtm)
        text = ' text' * 20
        # for index in range(50000):
        for index in range(500):
            line = f'{index}{text}\n'
            self.editTop.insertPlainText(line)
            self.editBtm.insertPlainText(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(800, 100, 600, 400)
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```